# how to monitor hadoop jobs?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler

Recently，I read a paper about Hadoop YARN scheduler. In the paper, there are some experiment graphs, these graphs are about every Hadoop jobs' memory utilization. Sorry, I have no reputation to post images.

I wonder how to get every Hadoop job metric about memory occupied. Is there any tools or need to write code yourself? Can someone help me? Forgive my poor English!

Comment: You can use ganglia to monitor the memory utilization

Comment: thanks，I have solved my problem